# Model login constraints based on time

Tags: database-design, authentication, constraints, data-modeling

Good morning,

for an existing web application I need to implement "time based login constraints". It means that for each user, later maybe each group, I can define timeslots when they are (not) allowed to log in into the system. As all data for the application is stored in database tables, I need to somehow create a way to model this idea in that way.

My first approach, I will try to explain it here:

- Create a tree of login constraints (called "timeslots") with the main "categories", like "workday", "weekend", "public holiday", etc. on the top level, which are in a "sorted" order (meaning "public holiday" has a higher priority than "weekday")
- for each top level node create subnodes, which have a finer timespan, like "monday", "tuesday", ...
- below that, create an "hour" level: 0, 1, 2, ..., 23. No further details are necessary.
- set every member to "allowed" by default
- For every member of the system create a `1:n` relationship `member:timeslots` which defines constraints, e.g. a member A may have `A:monday-forbidden` and `A:tuesday-forbidden`
- Do a depth-first search at every login and check if the member has a constraint.
  Why a depth first search? Well, I thought that it may be that a member has the rules:

`A:monday->forbidden`, `A:monday-10->allowed`, `A:mondey-11->allowed`

So a login on monday at 12:30 would fail, but one at 10:30 succeed.

For performance reasons I could break the relational database paradigm and set a flag for every entry in the member-to-timeslots-table which is set to true if the member has information set for "finer" timeslots, but that's a second step.

Is this model in principle a good idea? Are there existing models?

Thanks.

Comment: I chose to go with an easier model which roughly follows the cron syntax. All rules for a user will be checked in an order and if one matches, that one will be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  That sounds way more complicated than I'd want to deal with.  I'd just create a table like this:

Allowed_Login_Times

- Weekday_Start
- Weekday_End
- Saturday_Start
- Satruday_End
- Sunday_Start
- Sunday_End
- Holiday_Start
- Holiday_End

Each column would be an int from 0 to 23 representing the hour.

I'd let the application decide what hour it was and which column should be checked.

Your solution is more flexible, but I can't imagine trying to create an admin GUI to maintain the data.

Comment: Well, the hour constraint must be possible to be defined per user.

Comment: Right, so either you add a user_id (or group_id) column to this table, or you add these columns to your user table.